# Ability to favorite or follow companies

Tags: feature-request, status-planned, stack-overflow-jobs

It would be nice if there were a way to follow a company on jobs to somehow be informed when they make new postings.

For example, I was looking at a posting where I might be a good fit for the back-end stack but the only position listed was front-end.  I might then follow the company to make it more likely I would learn about a future openings.

Comment: You can kind of do this via search. For instance, enter the following in search: `company:"stack overflow"`, then click the Create Alert button. That will subscribe you to emails about new jobs that match that search.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We are working on a feature that will let you do this from the company page. There aren't any specifics for me to share now as it's all subject to change.

While you wait the 6 to 8 weeks it's going to take us to get it released, you can create alerts as Mike suggested on his comment, that would email you whenever the company has a new position. You could even add more filters to that query, doing something like `[c#] company:"stack overflow"` so that it only notifies you when new listings matching your interests are published.

Here's how to do it in [Mike McCaughan](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/215552/mike-mccaughan)'s words (copied from the comment):

> Enter the following in search: `company:"stack overflow"`, then click
>   the Create Alert button. That will subscribe you to emails about new
>   jobs that match that search.

Comment: I see the answer was edited to say to "6 to 8 weeks".  Here I thought the initial omission of units on "6 to 8" was intentional and communicating it was unknown entirely unknown when it would be scheduled and released :-)

Comment: nah, don't over think it, I just suck a at this... I keep reading my answers and finding things I missed ;)